# After the server change, some users encounter a white page?

Tags: reactjs, caching, server, dns

After the server change, some of the users encounter a white page when they want to enter the site. The browser can enter when they clear the cache. How can I do this without the user noticing?

Or do you have any other suggestions for solving the problem?

When I examine it, it seems that the cache directory is entered as ~/.npm or %APP_DATA%\npm-cache on the jenkins job.  When I examine the server, there is ~/.npm/_cacache directory. The tmp directory inside is updated and empty. but other directories have outdated records (content-v2 and index-v5)

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly because the `index.html` file is cached on the client-side. Inside the HTML file, it attempts to import some JS files. I'm not sure which React framework are you using, but most, if not all of them will generate bundled JS files with hashes in the file name, e.g. `component-js-accf25d88e9116ff2515.js`. This ensures the file names are always different in every single build.

Now, if the client cached `index.html`, it will include the old filenames of your JS bundles. When you update the application, those old files will no longer exist. And if you are using a client-side framework like `create-react-app`, none of the JS bundles will be fetched and result in empty HTML content, i.e. white screen.

Comment: it is trying to pull the old js package file and it has changed with the new version. I got it so far. So how can I solve this without taking action from the user?

Comment: You can set the `cache-control` header to `cache-control: public, max-age=0, must-revalidate`

Comment: I added it, I saw it in the reply, but the white page problem was not resolved. When I examine it, the data stored in the local store remains. Does not auto reset. i tried this too , Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate

Comment: Because the old `index.html` is still cached according to the old cache rules. You have to ask the clients to clear the browser cache.

Comment: Can't we do this automatically? telling this to every user may not be a good contact for the company

Comment: The issue is, you have instructed the client's browser to cache the `index.html`. The browser is following your instruction. You can either wait for the cache to expire, which may take a long time depending on your previous cache setting, or ask the clients to do the manual work.

Comment: It's been a month and there are still people who have this problem. So there was no automatic reset. It's also not good to recursively tell customers to clear your cookies. Not everyone has to know this. Isn't there a solution to this? via service worker vs.